# text conversion into random upper and lowercase in java

Tags: java

I wanted suggestions on how can I code an app to convert text into alternating upper and lowercase.

Example:

> hello good morning

converted to

> hElLo GoOd MoRnInG

Comment: Your question title asks for random upper/lower case, but then the text of the question itself asks for alternating case.  Which one do you actually want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen alternating case ,sorry my bad

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
String str = "hello good morning";
char[] letters = str.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(letters.length);
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(letters[i]));
    else {
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(letters[i]));
    }
}
```

First letter is lower-case, second letter is upper-case, third letter is lower-case, etc. As requested, alternating upper and lower case. If you want to start with upper-case, rather than lower-case as in the above code, simply change the condition in the `if` statement to...

```java
if (i % 2 == 1) {
```

Comment: While this code generally works, it doesn't take into account the fact that spaces (and probably other characters, must be ignored. I think [Arvind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789460/507738) is better in the sense of that it fullfills the exact requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Random pattern:

```
System.out.println(
        "hello good morning".chars() // get chars
        .map(i -> new Random().nextDouble() > 0.5 ? Character.toUpperCase(i) : Character.toLowerCase(i)) // change the case
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)); // collect to string
```

Alternative pattern:

```
String str = "hello good morning";
System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, str.length()) // range of length
        .map(i -> i % 2 == 1 ? Character.toUpperCase(str.codePointAt(i)): Character.toLowerCase(str.codePointAt(i))) // map the values accordingly
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)); // collect to string
```

Comment: `toString()` is kind of useless in this case if you are using `Syso` since `toString()` will be automatically invoked.

Comment: FYI, streams API supported in Android version 7.0 (Nougat), API level 24.

Comment: This answer may be inefficient, because it creates a new `Random` object for each step of the map operation.

Answer (score 2):

All of the existing answers on this page are great but none of them fulfils the exact requirement. The requirement is to switch the case of only the next alphabet, not every character (which is how every existing answer on this page is doing). Given below is the precise way of doing it:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello good morning";
        char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean switchCase = false;
        for (char ch : charArr) {
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
                if (switchCase) {
                    sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
                } else {
                    sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
                }
                switchCase = !switchCase;
            } else {
                sb.append(ch);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hElLo GoOd MoRnInG
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String StudlyCaps(String txt) {

    Random random = new Random();

    char[] letters = txt.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(letters.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

        if (random.nextBoolean()){
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(letters[i]));
        }
        else {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(letters[i]));
        }
        
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```